# Fix bootstrap field columns on mobiles

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask-wtforms

I'm create a simple webpage to present on the pc web browser as well as in mobiles.

I'm using python Flask to create it. Here is the code of my template.

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" >
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="text-center">Header</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center">Subtitle.</h2>
            <p class="text-center">Comment.</p>
            <br>
        </div>
        <form class="form form-inline" method="post" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ wtf.form_errors(form, hiddens="only") }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.urlid,placeholder='Hint') }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
                <span class="help-block text-center">Help block.</span>
            </div>
            <p>Comment.</p>
        </form>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
{%- endblock %}
```

The result in the pc browser is OK. See it:

[image]

But the form in my mobile is not inline. See it:

[image].

How can I fix it? I tried this  but didn't work either.

```
{{ wtf.form_field(form.urlid,placeholder='Hint',horizontal_columns=('sm', 2, 4)) }}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile is below the `sm` breakpoint for bootstrap, so the input is taking up the whole width.

If you want the input to take up the width you've specified, use the `xs` breakpoint.

`{{ wtf.form_field(form.urlid,placeholder='Hint',horizontal_columns=('xs', 2, 4)) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a mobile first grid system. So it takes 12 grids for `xs` devices. Thats the reason, the form is not inline in the mobile view.

If you like to get the same view as in the desktop or large devices than mobile, pls change the default breakpoint setting from `xs-12` to `xs-8` for the **Textbox** and `xs-4` for the **Button**.

Thanks.